# convert large dataset to bytes array using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, serialization, dataset, arrays

I am able to convert dataset to bytes array using [this link](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/111506.aspx) and this code:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, dtUsers); // dtUsers is a DataTable

byte[] bytes = stream.GetBuffer();
```

But the system taking it's toll lot memory , freezing when resultset  returning 500000 or more records.Is there any better way to accomplish the same with one shot.Any help would be appreciated.Database is SQL Server 2005 and VS 2008 for C#.

Comment: I assume 5 lacs are 500.000(edited accordingly).

Comment: Why do you want to serialise the dataset, could be a bit of room for some lateral thinking here.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1224151.aspx :)

Comment: Tony We have to serialize and compress Data (dataset) and send this data using WCF service.Serialization taking time and memory as well.If simultaneous request come application is freezing.